# Display tasklist icons only - don't display tasklist text

Tags: lua, awesome-wm

*Please note: There is already an answer for awesome version 3.5 on SO. That answer does not apply to awesome 4.0 and this is not a duplicate*

I just switched to Awesome 4.0. I would like to hide the text from my tasklist, and only show the icons.

I've combed through th documentation and it doesn't look like this is supported out of the box. There was a hack-around for Awesome 3.5 but I couldn't get it working in 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set the tag to `t.icon_only = true` and it will stop showing the text. There is an open bug that list undocumented APIs and it's part of it. In 4.0, we tried to improve the doc a lot, but given how much had to be documented, this is still work-in-progress.

As with all undocumented APIs, it may change at anytime until it is documented. However this one look rather simple and should not change. It isn't documented because it's not a "real" property. It has no getter or setter and is apparently the result of a drive by contribution commit with no documentation (added Mon Apr 13 11:36:09 2009 +0100)

Comment: Where can I find that bug entry with undocumented API? I'm sorry, I'm quite new to awesome and LUA, not sure what `t` is in your context? theme? tasklist?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't pay enough attention. You will have to port the taglist `icon_only` code from taglist.lua to tasklist.lua (the code is nearly identical) and submit a pull request.